# Laravel - Insert Array of data into database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello how can I achieve to insert data on an array? using eloquent? right now i have this on my

**Controller**

```
public function insertSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $employAdd = [];

    foreach($employAdd as $key){

        $employeeTimeSet = new Schedule;
        $employeeTimeSet->employee_no = $request->input('hidEmployeeno'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->last_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeLast'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->first_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->date_today = $request->input('dateToday'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->time_in = $request->input('timeIn'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->time_out = $request->input('timeOut'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->save();    

    }


  }
```

**View**

See here my view? the dates here are arrays then when I insert this into the database the output or the data that is being inserted is the last data why is that?

```
         {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">

                    <small>Employee No. and Name: </small><b><i> {{ $employee->employee_no }} : {{ $employee->last_name }}, {{ $employee->first_name }}</i></b>

                    <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeno[]" value='<?php echo $employee->employee_no ?>'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeLast[]" value='<?php echo $employee->last_name ?>'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeFirst[]" value='<?php echo $employee->first_name ?>'>
                    <hr>

                </div>

        </div>


        @php
        $today = today(); 
        $dates = []; 

        for($i=1; $i < $today->daysInMonth + 1; ++$i) {
            $dates[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, $i)->format('F-d-Y');
        }
    @endphp

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>DATE TODAY</th>
            <th>TIME IN</th>
            <th>TIME OUT</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($dates as $date)
                <tr>
                    <td><b>{{ $date }}</b></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="dateToday[]" value="{{ $date }}">
                    <td><input type="time" name="timeIn[]" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
                    <td><input type="time" name="timeOut[]" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
                    <td> {{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-clock">&nbsp;&nbsp;SET TIME</i>',['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',  'style'=>"display: inline-block;"])}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

          {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

From our chat, I updated the answer. The following in your controller should work:

```
public function insertSchedule(Request $request)
{
    Schedule::create([
        'employee_no' => $request->input('hidEmployeeno'),
        'last_name' => $request->input('hidEmployeeLast'),
        'first_name' => $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst'),
        'date_today' => $request->input('dateToday'),
        'time_in' => $request->input('timeIn'),
        'time_out' => $request->input('timeOut'),
    ]);
}
```

Then you need to update your form to something like the following, notice the Form tag belongs to each row that you want to insert.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <small>Employee No. and Name: </small><b><i> {{ $employee->employee_no }} : {{ $employee->last_name }}, {{ $employee->first_name }}</i></b>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

@php
$today = today(); 
$dates = []; 

for($i=1; $i < $today->daysInMonth + 1; ++$i) {
    $dates[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, $i)->format('F-d-Y');
}
@endphp

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DATE TODAY</th>
            <th>TIME IN</th>
            <th>TIME OUT</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($dates as $date)
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeno" value='<?php echo $employee->employee_no ?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeLast" value='<?php echo $employee->last_name ?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeFirst" value='<?php echo $employee->first_name ?>'>
    <tr>
        <td><b>{{ $date }}</b></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="dateToday" value="{{ $date }}">
        <td><input type="time" name="timeIn" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
        <td><input type="time" name="timeOut" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
        <td>{{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-clock">&nbsp;&nbsp;SET TIME</i>', ['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm', 'style'=>"display: inline-block;"])}}</td>
    </tr>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sir it has an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: , what is the error sir how can we solved it ? thank you so muchhh

Comment: We are looping over one of the values in your view. What is the output of ```dd($data)```

Comment: here is the output sir `array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "fMysI7wGe3rtC8cJJ8ADqemazyykFiOO7XXDLfy8"
  "hidEmployeeno" => "10310"
  "hidEmployeeLast" => "Rizal"
  "hidEmployeeFirst" => "Jose"
  "dateToday" => "January-31-2019"
  "timeIn" => null
  "timeOut" => null
]`

Comment: the array is also getting the last data sir, why is that :(

Comment: Then you changed the view, in the view your ```hidEmployeeno``` variable is indexed, ie. an array, but in the dump it is singular. I updated my answer for this case.

Comment: hey sir it has an error `Add [employee_no] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Schedule].` .. if im not mistaken this is fillable? but how can i create the fillable sir? or am i wrong??

Comment: You will have to check that in your ```Schedule``` model then, chances are the ```$fillable``` is not set. You can look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187460/discussion-between-leon-vismer-and-summer-winter).

Comment: yes sir i got it and it inserted the data but why is that I insert January-02-2019 , then the data that has been inserted was January-31-2019 :(