# Laravel Inserting Data Only the Last List or Data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to insert the data specifically look at my page.

[image]

When I set time the data will be inserted. But what I have right now is the data that is inserted is the very last data on this table which is `January-31-2019` how can I fix it so when I insert data, the data will insert any of the data that is list on the table.

**Controller**

```php
public function insertSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $employeeTimeSet = new Schedule;
    $employeeTimeSet->employee_no = $request->input('hidEmployeeno');
    $employeeTimeSet->last_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeLast');
    $employeeTimeSet->first_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst');
    $employeeTimeSet->date_today = $request->input('dateToday');
    $employeeTimeSet->time_in = $request->input('timeIn');
    $employeeTimeSet->time_out = $request->input('timeOut');
    $employeeTimeSet->save();

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Click PLAN TIME! Employee Time Set!',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification, 'Employee Time Set');
}
```

**View**

```php
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <small>Employee No. and Name:</small>
        <b><i> {{ $employee->employee_no }} : {{ $employee->last_name }}, {{ $employee->first_name }}</i></b>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeno" value='<?php echo $employee->employee_no ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeLast" value='<?php echo $employee->last_name ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeFirst" value='<?php echo $employee->first_name ?>'>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
@php
    $today = today(); 
    $dates = []; 

    for($i=1; $i < $today->daysInMonth + 1; ++$i) {
        $dates[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, $i)->format('F-d-Y');
    }
@endphp

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DATE TODAY</th>
        <th>TIME IN</th>
        <th>TIME OUT</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($dates as $date)
        <tr>
            <td><b>{{ $date }}</b></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="dateToday" value="{{ $date }}">
            <td><input type="time" name="timeIn" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="timeOut" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
            <td> {{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-clock">&nbsp;&nbsp;SET TIME</i>',['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',  'style'=>"display: inline-block;"])}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: here you create row input with same name. that`s why you last entry only storing into the variable..

Comment: Please explain more. I did not understand what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Insert Array of data into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412957/laravel-insert-array-of-data-into-database)

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already?

Comment: I answered on your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412233/laravel-insert-data-inserts-the-last-array-lists-only/54414681#54414681)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using one form with multiple inputs in it and there is no unique name to them. If you inspect the code, your form will have 31 inputs with name *timeIn* and 31 inputs with name *timeOut*.

When you submit the form, It picks the last *timeIn* and *timeOut*.

**Two soluctions**

1. Make multiple forms (put form tags in while loop, it will create 31 forms in the page)
2. Use ajax to send data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [] for your textbox names. Example : name[] and you need to use a loop to post it. Example - [how to get post from same name textboxes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990367/how-to-get-post-from-same-name-textboxes-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the @Swaroop's Answer there is another option. You can make array of these fields in the same form and submit them. and at the server end, you will have to loop through posted array so that you can process them further.